# Why is mock location jumping back to real position

Tags: android, android-location

I added a test provider using `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` as provider name like described here

https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/

In Google Maps app, I see location jumping between mocked location and real location, and then back to mocked location.

Why is jumping to real location and how can I stop it?

Maybe I misunderstand how to use mock locations. I haven't found any official documentation available.

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have your location settings configured in a way that your phone (and apps) can use both the location from the GPS sensor and the location from the cells and wi-fi. Since the coming of the Fused Location Provider, the way the system fetches your location got a bit murkier.

When you mock the position you are only able to mock the GPS sensor readings (this is also true for when you mock the position through the simulator settings).
So when the system feeds Google Maps with a position from the GPS sensor it gives it the fake one, and when it provides the position from other sensors it will be the real one.

To test that I'm correct, you can switch location settings to "Device only" and you should only get the fake positions.

Unfortunately there's no way to mock the other sensors readings.

Comment: So how can i test FusedLocationProviderClient using mock locations? 
Is there a way to know the "original" provider of the Location object (getting "fused")?

Comment: As far as my experience with the FusedLocationProvider goes, you are no longer able to know the source of the single location, this is almost certainly a way for the Play Services Location library to have an API that delivers location in a sensor agnostic way. There's an "accuracy" information attached to the location, but I haven't found a way to match that value with the sensor since wi-fi and cell provided position accuracy can vary a lot depending on the situation.

Comment: I tried FusedLocationProviderClient.setMockMode which according to documentation:
"The underlying providers (network and gps) will be stopped (except by direct LocationManager access), and only locations specified in setMockLocation(Location) will be reported..." but getting SecurityException: "must be selected as the mock location application in developer settings" which doesn't make much sense, i don't want my app to be the mock, i simply want to switch to mock mode.

Comment: In order to mock your own location, you need to be a system-wide recognized mock app. That makes the existence of .setMockMode quite confusing.

Comment: I guess that switching off network and gps surely is something that most app shouldn't be able to do without extra permissions.

A (bad) way to mock location could be to abstract the layer providing the location and switch the implementation if you are in "test" mode or in certain app variants. Of course that will stop working as soon as the app gets killed in the background, plus it won't work for geofence transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off *Wi-Fi scanning* / *Bluetooth scanning* in the *Location Settings* to stop jumping to preserve mock location.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a location mocker app and usually this happened if you have
"Google location Accuracy" option -> ON , and you start injecting the mock locations, if there is a small gap between the sent mock locations then usually you will have this jump .

To avoid this I would **turn off "Google location Accuracy"** from settings . then start injecting the mock locations .