# Unable to perform work on the background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So, I'm following [this tutorial](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service) to implement a Service in my app. I implemented the Service succesfully. The service is activated and the notification is shown normally. Everything is fine except that I was not able to do work on the background thread. Please see below.

My goal is to set a mock location.

This is my `onStartCommand` for my Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText("hi")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();


    startForeground(1, notification);

    //do work on a background thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            startMockLocation(); // doesn't actually mock device's location!
        }
    }).start();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

However, when I do this, it works fine but it's not efficient:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {



    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText("hi")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();


    startForeground(1, notification);

// works great
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        startMockLocation();
        //other stuff
    }
}, 0, 1000);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Mock location method:

```
public void startMockLocation(){ // this code is fine, nothing to fix here, something is wrong with the thread though :(

    FusedLocationProviderClient locationProvider =  new FusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
    locationProvider.setMockMode(true);

    Location loc = new Location("gps");

    Location mockLocation = new Location("gps"); // a string
    mockLocation.setLatitude(48.8566);
    mockLocation.setLongitude(2.3522);
    mockLocation.setAltitude(loc.getAltitude());
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    mockLocation.setAccuracy(1f);
    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mockLocation.setBearingAccuracyDegrees(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setVerticalAccuracyMeters(0.1f);
        mockLocation.setSpeedAccuracyMetersPerSecond(0.01f);
    }
    locationProvider.setMockLocation(mockLocation);

}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @Mr.AF I'm unable to set a mock location from inside `onStartCommand `. But, it works normally on the Main Activity.

Comment: Do you know that all methods are called properly? What happens when you put logs into `run` and `startMockLocation`?

Answer (score 3):

If by not being able to do work from background thread you mean that you don't see the effect of startMockLocation(), it depends on if there is any computation that depends on startMockLocation(). If you don't join the thread or block somewhere and wait for your background thread to complete, your main thread might very well run til termination before your background thread finishes its work. That would look like your background thread has not done anything.

Comment: yes. that's correct, I don't see the effect of `startMockLocation`. Could you please support your answer with some code? I'll then proceed to accept your answer.

Comment: so when you execute startMockLocation() on the main thread, everything works fine? If it does work fine when it's executed sequentially, could you try to print a message from startMockLocation() to see if the code is even reached?

Comment: The code is even reached on the thread. **But in the thread, `startMockLocation` doesn't mock the device's location like it usually does** << That's the issue.

Comment: Like it usually does? You mean when you put startMockLocation()  on the main thread, it works fine? Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445821/why-is-mock-location-jumping-back-to-real-position?rq=1 is what's happening ?

Comment: _You mean when you put startMockLocation() on the main thread, it works fine?_ Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: _Maybe this stackoverflow.com/questions/51445821/… is what's happening ?_ And no, that's not what's happeninng. `startMockLocation` simply doesn't change the device's location like it should.

Comment: Can you do a loop checking if the thread is alive immediately after you spawn it and maybe prints out the thread state in the loop? We can see if the thread goes through a lifecycle that we expect.

Comment: Yes, the loop runs and is alive. Output: `System.out: Thread-5
2020-05-23 20:50:33.582 17402-17508/? I/System.out: state = RUNNABLE`

Comment: Since you are not using a thread pool and just spawn a new thread whenever `onStartCommand` is called, your worker thread should be terminated once `run()` returns. If the loop that checks whether that thread is still alive never exits, it means `run()` never runs til completion. Just being in the RUNNABLE state doesn't men it ran. It sorta defeats the purpose of running mock location in a separate thread, but can you try to join the thread after you call it if you aren't able to observe its state change from the loop?

Comment: never mind, I saw your newest edit. Maybe you can try to check whether the tasks returned from `setMockMode` and `setMockLocation` are successful, if not, you just run it again?